# Failed to resolve dependencies error at dnx . test

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit.net

I am working in a ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 project with Xunit testing, but when I try to execute `dnx . test` I get this error:

```
dnx : System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
At line:1 char:1
+ dnx . test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.InvalidO...ersion=v4.5.1'::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0-beta-23019
   System.Collections 4.0.10-beta-23019
   System.Linq 4.0.0-beta-23019
   System.Runtime 4.0
.10-beta-23019
   System.Threading 4.0.10-beta-23019
   xunit 2.1.0-beta4
   xunit.runner.dnx 2.1.0-beta4

Searched Locations:
  D:\Project\{name}\project.json
  D:\Project\MrBellhop.Test\src\{name}\project.json
  D:\Project\MrBellhop.Test\test\{name}\project.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\{name}.dll
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\{name}.dll
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll

Try running 'dnu restore'.

   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkName targetFramework)
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System.InvalidO...ersion=v4.5.1'::String) [], RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I have followed [this manual](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html) and although I implement a simple example I get the same error.

My **project.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Project.Test",
  "authors": [ "" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

I am using Asp.net 5 Beta 6

**Do you know how to solve this error?**

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file and the entire output of `dnx . test` after you set the `DNX_TRACE=1` environment variable?

Comment: What version of DNX are you using? You don't have to speficy path anymore [as of beta7](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/52). E.g.: try `dnx test`.

Comment: dnx test returns "Please specify the command to run"

Comment: I have added project.json and the complete output after set DNX_TRACE=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I was trying to execute `dnx . test` in the root folder, instead of Test Project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the hardest time with this as well.  I found that the path is also case sensitive.

Example:

```
PM> cd src
PM> cd busweb
PM> dnx . ef
dnx : System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'busweb' from C:\Users\scoll\Google Drive\Clients\MECCSoft\BusWeb\src\busweb
```

But...

```
PM> cd..
PM> cd BusWeb
PM> dnx . ef

                     _/\__
               ---==/    \\
         ___  ___   |.    \|\
        | __|| __|  |  )   \\\
        | _| | _|   \_/ |  //|\\
        |___||_|       /   \\\/\\

 7.0.0-beta5-13549
```

The project was created as BusWeb, and that is how you need to navigate to the directory or specify the path as well.

Hope this helps!